# How to prove that if the square matrix $A$ is singular, then $AA^T$ is also singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

If a square matrix $A$ is singular, then, <strike>for any</strike> there exists a vector $\mathbf{v} \neq \mathbf{0}$ in the null space of $A$, so that $A\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$.

I have attempted answering my question by multiplying both sides of the above by $A^T$ to yield

$$A^T A\mathbf{v} = A^T \mathbf{0} = \mathbf{0}$$
$$A^T A\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$$

but don't know how to get any further.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: $A^TA$ is singular, conclude. By the way your first sentence should read "If $A$ is singular, there is $v\neq 0$ with $Av = 0$. As written, it's wrong

Comment: "for any vector $\mathbf{v}$ in the nullspace of $A$, $A\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$" is true for any matrix, singular or not, by definition of "nullspace". What being singular gives you is the existence of a vector $\mathbf{v}\neq\mathbf{0}$ in the nullspace.

Comment: @Andrew right you are, I'll correct it.

Comment: Your proof shows that $A^TA$ is singular. To show that $AA^T$ is singular, note that $A^T$ is also singular, so the same proof works with $A^T$ in place of $A$ and vice versa. Actually, if $A$ is singular, then $AB$ and $BA$ must also be singular for any square matrix $B$ with the same dimensions as $A$.

Comment: This is true for a square matrix.  It is not true for rectangular matrices.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang ahhh, that makes sense! Thus, if $A$ is singular, then $A^T$ is singular, so for any $\mathbf{w} \neq \mathbf{0}$ in the null space of $A^T$, $A^T\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{0}$. So, $AA^T \mathbf{w} = A\mathbf{0} = \mathbf{0}$, which means $AA^T$ must be singular. Thanks!!!

Comment: If $A$ is singular, that doesn't necessarily mean $A^T$ is singular. Consider $A =(1,0,0)$ as counterexample. The property only holds for square matrices and matrices whose height is greater than their width. Do we know if $A$ is square?

Comment: @user3257842 thanks for pointing that out. Indeed, I am assuming $A$ is square (my question stems from studying multivariate Gaussians, where $A$ is the matrix used to transform from an uncorrelated multivariate Gaussian with mean zero to a correlated multivariate Gaussian, $\mathbf{y} = A\mathbf{x}$). I'll make that clear in the question now!

Comment: Your "correction" doesn't fix the issue of your first statement. Again, "for any vector $\mathbf{v}\neq\mathbf{0}$ in the null space of $A$, $A\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$" is true for **any** matrix, singular or not. Because for *any* vector $\mathbf{v}$ in the nullspace of $A$, zero or not, $A\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$. If the matrix is not singular, the statement is still true (by vacuity). What "singular" gives you is the **existence** of a nonzero $\mathbf{v}$ in the nullspace.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin To say "for any vector $\mathbf{v} \neq \mathbf{0}$ in the null space of $A$, $A\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$" would be a contradiction if it were not stated that $A$ is singular, given that there does not exist a non-zero vector $\mathbf{v}$ such that $A\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$ if $A$ is full rank.

Comment: No, it would not be a contradiction. You are saying "for all vectors $\mathbf{v}$ if $\mathbf{v}\neq\mathbf{0}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ is in the nullspace of $A$, then $A\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$." That statement is **true** for **any** matrix. If $A$ is non-singular then the antecedent is false, but the implication is true. The statement is true **always**, whether $A$ is singular or not singular.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see what you're getting at. It is $\textbf{always}$ true to say "for any vector $\mathbf{v}$ in the null space of $A$, $A\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$, but it would be a contradiction to add in the "for any $\mathbf{v} \neq \mathbf{0}$", because a full rank matrix has a trivial null space, where the only null vector is $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$.

Comment: For the third time, no, it would not be a contradiction. The following statement is **true**: for any $\mathbf{v}\neq \mathbf{0}$ that lies in the nullspace of the identity  matrix  $I$, $I\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$. It is true because the antecedent is always false, and an implication in which the antecedent is false is **true**. What would be a contradiction would be to assert that **there exists** a nonzero vector in the nullspace when $A$ is nonsingular. But "any" is a "for  all" statement, and for all statements are true when you quantify over the empty set.

Comment: PS you can get italic text by enclosing it in asterisks, and boldface with two asterisks. Don't use MathJax to do boldface or italics. `**bold text**` and `*italic text*` give **bold text** and *italic text*.

Comment: For me it is very simple: $A$ is singular, and thus has a non-trivial null space. Thus, there exists some non-zero vector $\mathbf{v}$ such that $A\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$. Thus, my statement is not incorrect. I believe we are both on the same page, so would appreciate not getting lost in semantics. Thank you for mentioning the **bold text** and *italic text*!

Comment: Compare "has" with "for any". One of them is an existential statement.. The other is a universal statement. What you wrote in the post is true for **any** matrix, not just nonsingular ones. I said so from the very beginning, but you still don't seem to be getting the point. You say "Because $A$ is singular, then this thing which is true for **any** matrix is true for $A$." That statement is *misleading*, because the conclusion holds for any matrix. If you'd said "Because $A$ is nonsingular, **there exists* a nonzero $\mathbf{v}$ such  that..." then that wouldn't be misleading.

Comment: It's not "getting lost in semantics", is pointing  out that your first statement is **vacuously true** by the definition of "nullspace". It provides *nothing*. That's not "semantics", that's bad proof writing, and bad mathematics. It is tantamount to saying "Because $A$ is nonsingular, every element of the empty set is green". Sure, that's a true statement. It's *misleading*, and it doesn't provide anything of substance, though.

Comment: Then, please change the first sentence to assert the existence of a nonzero vector $\mathbf{v}$ for which $A\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$. As Arturo Magidin pointed out, the statement that $A\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$ for any $\mathbf{v}$ in the null space of $A$ holds by definition regardless of whether $A$ is singular or not, or whether $\mathbf{v}$ is the zero vector or not.

Comment: From the comments here there seems to have been some scope creep in the definition of "singular matrix" since I learnt linear algebra 50 or so years ago. The notion of singular matrix was only applied to square matrices then and I can find no textbook on my shelves and almost no pointers on the web with any other reading of the term. Why has this become so much more complicated?